# what would be the folder name according to resolution and language in android drawable folder?

Tags: android, resolution

friends,

i want to support multiple resolutions and languages in my android application.

now problem is

i have following folders in my drawable folder

1)drawable-hdpi
2)drawable-ldpi
3)drawable-mdpi

and for languages

1) drawable-en-rUS

what would be the combination of these? so that android could  understand(which folder to use) for example   low resolution with english language support folder.

do i need to combine these both names or what is the solution?

any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

E.g. `drawable-en-rUS-port-hdpi`. See the [docs](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html#BestMatch) for further info.